# Is there some nomenclature to get the integer value of a fraction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

There is some math nomenclature to represent the integer value of a fraction?

Say,

$$x \in \mathbb{R},\, \textbf{foo}(x) = \text{integer part of }x$$

Then

$$x = 1.823,\, \textbf{foo}(x) = 1$$

Comment: Worth noting is that this isn't the "integer value" of the fraction. It is the fraction truncated to the nearest integer.

Comment: @ZettaSuro, not the nearest integer, surely, as the nearest integer to $1.823$ is $2$.

Comment: @vadim123 but then that wouldn't be truncating, so $1$ would be the nearest integer that $1.823$ can be truncated to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integer part of $x$ is given by the somewhat ugly-looking $$\text{sgn}(x)\lfloor |x| \rfloor$$
which some authors abbreviate as $[x]$.  $\text{sgn}(x)$ denotes the [signum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signum_function) function. The [floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$works as expected for positive $x$, but $\lfloor -1.5\rfloor=-2$, which is not the expected $-1$ integer part of $-1.5$.